# How to include a signature in an extended module?

Tags: ocaml

Let's say we wanted to extend an existing module like `List`.

We would generally just `include` the module we want to extend, and then add the new methods to its structure:

```
# module List = struct
    include List
    let addOne x = x + 1
  end;;
```

which gives us the signature:

```
module List :
  sig
    val length : 'a list -> int
    val compare_lengths : 'a list -> 'b list -> int
    val compare_length_with : 'a list -> int -> int
    :
    val addOne : int -> int
  end
```

Now if I wanted to explicitly extend the module's signature as well, I'd *try* to do something like:

```
# module List : sig
    val addOne : int -> int
  end = struct
    include List
    let addOne x = x + 1
  end;;
```

but now we see that our signature becomes:

```
module List :
  sig
    val addOne : int -> int
  end
```

By defining our own signature like this, we're excluding the `List`'s signature so our module's structure now doesn't include any of the original `List` methods.

Now, if this *wasn't* `List` but a module that I've personally created, then we could just define the signature separately and include it in the signature of the module we're extending.

```
# module List : sig
    include MY_LIST
    val addOne : int -> int
  end = struct
    include MyList
    let addOne x = x + 1
  end;;
```

But when we have something like `List`, or some other 3rd party module we're consuming, is there a way to extend it **and** include our own signature?

Is it possible to do this, and if not, is there a workaround that's commonly used to achieve similar behavior / is there a canonical way to handle these types of situations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `module type of` for those situations:

```
module List: sig
  include module type of List
  val more: unit
end = struct
  include List
  let more = ()
end
```